# Counting number of names using Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, reduce

If I am trying to count the number of people with certain names in a roster:
I should get an output something like `[Bob:2, Joe:1, Mary:1, Kane: 1]`

```
List<Person> names = Arrays.toList(Bob, Joe, Bob, Mary, Kane);

Map<String, List<int>> = names.stream().collect(
       Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getName,
            Collectors.reducing(
                0,
                //Is there a way here I can get the count of the names from the grouping by above this?
                Integer::sum
            )
       )
)
```

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, Collectors.counting())`.

Comment: `Collectors.summingInt(e->1) ` does the job, but `Collectors.counting()` is better.

Comment: Comments not for answers?

Answer (score 3):

Given the input:

```
List<Person> names = Arrays.asList(Bob, Joe, Bob, Mary, Kane);
```

You can use this lambda expression:

```
 Map<String, Integer> counts = names.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, counter -> 1, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new)
);
```

Which Produces:

```
{Bob=2, Joe=1, Mary=1, Kane=1}
```

Taking into account Federico's suggestions, the answer could be updated to:

```
Map<String, Long> counts = names.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Order of names now different.. OP may be fine with it, though

Comment: There is no reason to use `toConcurrentMap`, you can just use `toMap`, even if you used a parallel stream.

Comment: @Jayan: if order matters, you can use `Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, counter -> 1, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new)`

Comment: @Good comments @Holder. I updated the answer to include `toMap` and `LinkedHashMap::new`.Using `Person::getName` does require that Person is a functional interface, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: Damn cell dictionary... My comment was meant to be: `Person` doesn't need to be a functional interface, it's enough with the method reference. Also, `Collectors.groupingBy()` with `Collectors.counting()` is better than `Collectors.toMap()` with `counter -> 1` and `Integer::sum`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Good points Federico. I have updated the answer with your suggestions.

Comment: Hello everyone very sorry for the late response! But I had a quick question regarding your methods above. When you do `Map<String, Long> counts = names.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));` So will this group the list first by the same names? So it will group by all the names so you will have `[bob, bob, joe, mary, kane]`, then it will create *ONE* new LinkedHashMap, then finally it will count the occurrences of each item in the list created by the `groupingBy` and put it in the LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Almost. The statement first creates a new LinkedHashMap, which naturally sorts the keys. Then it is grouping by name as you described, so the name is the key of the map. The value for each key is the result of the `Collectors.counting()`, which will either place 1 as the value of the key in the map if this is the first occurance of the person's name, or it will increment the count if the person already exists as a key in the map.

Comment: Ok Thank you @pczeus for the help!